# VBA multiple Criteria in Array not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the following code; however, it is not displaying any results, if I do two criteria it works, but not more than than that.

```
Set FindRange = Range(Cells((ActiveCell.Row + 1), ActiveCell.Column), _
 Cells(LastRow,    ActiveCell.Column))
ActiveCell.AutoFilter , Field:=ActiveCell.Column, Criteria1:=Array("*Consumer*",_
 "*IENC*","*Non ICG*", "*Not past*", _"*Not a past*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished without an AutoFilter:

```
Dim r As Range
For Each r In FindRange
    v = r.Value
    If InStr(v, "Consumer") > 1 Or _
        InStr(v, "IENCE") > 0 Or _
        InStr(v, "Non ICG") > 0 Or _
        InStr(v, "Not past") > 0 Or _
        InStr(v, "Not a past") > 0 Then
        r.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next r
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not support more than two criteria. As a rule, you cannot do anything from VBA that you cannot do through the interface. And using Excel UI, you can also enter only two criteria.